# How to stop casting when another app starts casting?

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast, android-cast-api

I run two applications, both of which use Cast SDK v2 and the `Remote Display` API. I start casting from App #1, then go to App #2, press the cast button and select a route.

**Expected:** App #2 starts casting, App #1 stops casting.

**Actual:** Immediately after I select a route, App #2's `MediaRouter.Callback.onRouteUnselected()` is called. Neither app's content shows up on the receiver, but App #1's notification controller remains.

I haven't seen this behavior in Cast SDK v3. Is there any way in Cast SDK v2 to ensure that a prior cast session stops  when another app starts casting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't done this yet but you can try implementing a [addUpdateListener](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/chrome/chrome.cast.Session#addUpdateListener) and perform [session.stop](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/chrome_sender) when another one starts.

```
addUpdateListener(listener)
```

> Adds a listener that is invoked when the Session has changed. Changes
>   to the following properties will trigger the listener: statusText,
>   namespaces, status, and the volume of the receiver.
>
> Listeners should check the status property of the Session to determine
>   its connection status. The boolean parameter `isAlive` is deprecated in
>   favor of the status Session property. The isAlive parameter is still
>   passed in for backwards compatibility, and is true unless

```
status = chrome.cast.SessionStatus.STOPPED
```

Stop the app method:

```
function stopApp() {
    session.stop(onSuccess, onError);
}
```

Comment: This answer set me on the right path: now I add a listener that overrides `Cast.Listener.onApplicationMetadataChanged()` to determine if a new app has started casting, which seems to work. This requires adding both `CastRemoteDisplay.API` and `Cast.API` on the same `GoogleApiClient`; I have asked a [separate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39836864/can-one-use-castremotedisplay-api-and-cast-api-on-the-same-googleapiclient) to see if it is acceptable to use both APIs at once.