# Can one use CastRemoteDisplay.API and Cast.API on the same GoogleApiClient?

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast, android-cast-api

I am developing an Android app with `CastRemoteDisplay` (Cast SDK v2). When another app starts casting, I want to ensure my app stops casting, so I create my `CastOptionsBuilder` with the following listener:

```
Cast.Listener listener = new Cast.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void onApplicationMetadataChanged(ApplicationMetadata metadata) {
        String backdropId = "E8C28D3C"; // id of the Cast backdrop app
        if (!(metadata == null
            || metadata.getApplicationId().equals(backdropId)
            || metadata.getApplicationId().equals(MY_APP_ID)) {
            mMediaRouter.unselect(MediaRouter.UNSELECT_REASON_STOPPED);
        }
    }
};
```

Then setup the `GoogleApiClient` with:

```
GoogleApiClient client = (new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this, callbacks, connectFailListener))
                .addApi(CastRemoteDisplay.API, castRemoteDisplayOptionsBuilder.build())
                .addApi(Cast.API, castOptionsBuilder.build())
                .build();
```

My question: is it permitted to use both `CastRemoteDisplay.API` and `Cast.API` on the same `GoogleApiClient`?

Comment: Did you try using them both on the same GoogleApiClient? If yes, what happened?

Comment: I've used both and haven't seen any issues yet. My concern is that CastRemoteDisplay.API may call Cast.API under the hood, which might cause subtle bugs.